# SKScene in a SpriteView in SwiftUI has size 1?

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I'm confused about the cooridinates in a SpriteView in a SwiftUI app.

I have a [small program](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/Spriteoscope) I use for fooling around in Swift. It draws a SKScene with a grid of 64 x 64 squares, which I call "pixels", and then does color animation by changing their color. At the top of the SKScene setup code is this:

```
let pixelSize = min(self.size.width / Double(numColumns), self.size.height / Double(numRows))
```

Then I draw the grid by looping from -ve self.size.width/64 to +ve self.size.width/64 and making squares of pixelSize, thereby centering them in SK's 0-in-the-center. The resulting SKScene is then placed in NSViewController or UIView.

I was reading a SwiftUI [intro on Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-integrate-spritekit-using-spriteview) and became intrigued with the simplicity of the code, so I decided to convert the app SUI. This is trivial using SpriteView. Running this results in the content all being pushed to the lower left corner:

[image]

In the debugger, I find that the dimensions of the view are 0,0 to 1,1, which is unexpected. This results in the pixels being the correct size, because they're scaled to the view. However, as you can see, they are positioned incorrectly with all the -ve values off-screen.

I thought this was order of operations, that the SKScene was being called before the screen was laid out, but no. I wrapped the SpriteView in a GeometryReader and found that the size is indeed the 480x480 I expect, and that the Scene's initalizer *is* called after the SpriteView is set up.

So why is 0,0 in the lower left and not the center, and why is the size in the SKScene 1 by 1? I looked in SpriteView and SpriteView.options dox, but I don't see any hint of this. What have I missed?

```
@State private var scene = SpriteoscopeScene()

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("pause") { scene.pauseKalidescope() } .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
        }.padding()
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("reset") { scene.setupKalidescope() } .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
        }.padding()

    }
    .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
}
```

Comment: did you put `self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` in your GameScene didMove(to view)? this would likely have been done in your ViewController before transition to Swift UI and hence could have been lost

Comment: @fault - I did not do this in either the new or old code, perhaps this is something the SUI code is doing behind the scenes? In any event, if the issue is on the SK side I'll add this line and see what happens. Thanks... and I love that to reply you you, your are at fault :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to follow up. @Fault's suggestion is correct. It seems when the SK is embedded the coordinates are moved to match the container. That is unexpected, but once you know its there it's a single change to make it all work again.